# Add image to canvas using paper JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

I used normal javascript to add image to canvas and this is the code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas_image();

function canvas_image(){
    can_img = new Image();
    can_img.src = 'Chrysanthemum.jpg';
    can_img.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(can_img, 100, 100);   
    }
}
```

How can i add image to canvas using **paperJS** library?

Comment: PaperJS provides tutorials. Have you seen them?

Comment: Yes i referred it but i could not find adding image to canvas. Is it possible to add image to canvas without image tag in paperJS as mentioned above

Comment: http://paperjs.org/reference/raster#raster-id

Answer (score 10):

Quoting from the [paperjs.org tutorial on rasters](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/working-with-rasters/):

> Images need to already be loaded when they are added to a Paper.js project. Working with local images or images hosted on other websites may throw security exceptions on certain browsers.

So you need an image somewhere that is preferably [visually hidden](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/a20a3c76d541d40ffb75a8f02c8c0f7b05773e51/css/main.css#L127-L136):

```
<img id="mona" class="visuallyhidden" src="mona.jpg" width="320" height="491">
```

And the [PaperScript](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/) code could look like this:

```
// Create a raster item using the image tag with id="mona"
var raster = new Raster('mona');
```

Then you can reposition, scale or rotate like so:

```
// Move the raster to the center of the view
raster.position = view.center;

// Scale the raster by 50%
raster.scale(0.5);

// Rotate the raster by 45 degrees:
raster.rotate(45);
```

And here is a [paperjs.org sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/VY9BbwIhEIX/yoSkcZtU8KAXG0/GYy965YIw3UV3gcDoxjT97wXWbmK48Jj3vnn8MKcGZFt2uiLpjn0w7U3RdxXBDi3swHh9G9AR1xEV4aHHohrJ8liy90/p8oWnqLNXso4obIUIKmC8JO5jK+hGPlrVJ2EH1WISo49X69rlaKlbRpUIYxKDd4pfQkY+idZUYHmXTLq5xtmbB1choDP7zvamyebSohwhYF9bgoIJDJZwgFvK+4A6hFoBSLVQtoM1u0XZsJCu/PiZ2YHDEY5VNNN82pD5X/6OlfT0kq9K52pZ+e+q7hZH6SYHDz5Zst5lbHnnk/Wfd9KqfwGeH7BZvc3pVObNim/mBkdP5YevkfUGDLYRMW3naKzGZp2j7PcP) to play with.

Answer (score 2):

First, If you want to work with JavaScript directly look at [this tutorial](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/). 
Once you understand it, you would have something like this to load image in  raster

```
paper.install(window);
window.onload = function() {
    // Setup directly from canvas id:
    paper.setup('myCanvas');
    var raster = new paper.Raster({source: 'Chrysanthemum.jpg', position: view.center});
}
```